# During insertion of values to array, the values are correct. But after that, I get different values

Tags: c, arrays

I created a function which should return an array of indexes of some specific number.
The function attributes are: size of array , array, number and a pointer.

In the example below I get different values. There are two places where I check the values: 
 1) After the Insertion: Which looks correct
 2) during Iteration over the returned array: Which returns different values, including addresses(why?)

```
These are the returned values: 

During insertion:
3
11
17
20
21
23
6
Pointed array size : 6

During iteration:
3
11
17
21
2334102057621532978
3617293411120723765
```

```
int main()
{
    size_t sizeToBeReturned;
    int arrayOfInt[] = {12, 15, 2, 8, 13, 3, 14, 1, 13, 6, 0, 8, 14, 15, 14, 14, 2, 8, 0, 15, 8, 8, 9, 8, 0, 14};
    size_t size = sizeof(arrayOfInt) / sizeof(int);
    size_t *returnedArray = find_all(size, arrayOfInt, 8, &sizeToBeReturned);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeToBeReturned; i++) {
        printf("%ld\n", returnedArray[i]);
        //when I iterate the returned array, the values comes massed up
    }
    return 0;
}

size_t *find_all(size_t a, const int array[a], int number, size_t * z)
{
    //printf("Array size: %zu\n", a);

    size_t *toReturnArray = NULL;
    size_t sizeOfArray = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (array[i] == number) {

            if (toReturnArray == NULL) {
                toReturnArray = (size_t *) malloc(sizeof(int));
            } else {
                toReturnArray = realloc(toReturnArray, (sizeOfArray) * sizeof(int));
            }

            toReturnArray[sizeOfArray] = i;
            printf("%ld\n", toReturnArray[sizeOfArray]);
            //Here I can see the correct value
                sizeOfArray++;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n", sizeOfArray);
    *z = sizeOfArray;
    return toReturnArray;
}
```

Comment: 1) Find out how much memory to malloc. 2) call malloc once. That should solve all your problems.

Comment: (1) If you allocate memory for an array of type `size_t`, don't use `sizeof(int)` in your size calculations. (2) You must cater for the eventual increment of the size of the array by allocating `sizeOfArray + 1` elements.

Comment: (By the way, `realloc(NULL, new_size)` will behave like `malloc(new_size)`, so you don't have to treat the first allocation as special case.)

Answer (score 1):

You allocate as a dynamic array of `int` but you consider it
as a dynamic array of `size_t` (larger) while reading/writing.

```
toReturnArray = (size_t *) malloc(sizeof(size_t)); // not sizeof(int)
toReturnArray = realloc(toReturnArray, (sizeOfArray+1) * sizeof(size_t));  // not sizeof(int)
```

If on your system, for example, `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(size_t)`
is 8, then the allocated memory is half the necessary size.

---

And something else I didn't see (thanks M Oehm) is the missing +1 in `realloc()`.

---

By the way, `realloc()` accepts a null pointer (then behaves like
`malloc()`) so the test is not necessary: just use the line with `realloc()`.